# Preserve leading whitespaces in commit message bodies (Redmine)

Tags: redmine

(see also [the same issue in GitLab](https://superuser.com/q/1815874/563952))

`git log` correctly displays indentation and alignment created by inserting leading whitespaces:

```
Do some cool stuff

class CoolStuffCapable
+ function doSomeCoolStuff does cool stuff
  ? beware of uncool limitations I need to fix later
    ? soonGettingSolved will be fixed within the current major release
    ? longLongWithUs will remain until at least the next major release
  ? there is a precondition I cannot get rid of
? moved field BoringStuffCapable::notSoInternalState to fix Feature Envy
  ? renamed to reallyInternalState accordingly
- constant MAYBE_UNUSED was unused

refs #1
```

Redmine 3.3.1 emits the commit message as formatted HTML text using `<p>` and `<br>` tags, with leading whitespaces trimmed out. Even if the whitespaces were still present though, browsers would not render them without additional `<pre>` or `<code>` tags.

```
Do some cool stuff

class CoolStuffCapable
+ function doSomeCoolStuff does cool stuff
? beware of uncool limitations I need to fix later
? soonGettingSolved will be fixed within the current major release
? longLongWithUs will remain until at least the next major release
? there is a precondition I cannot get rid of
? moved field BoringStuffCapable::notSoInternalState to fix Feature Envy
? renamed to reallyInternalState accordingly
- constant MAYBE_UNUSED was unused

refs #1
```

Can I make it display the correct message?
Can I make it just emit the output of `git log` (which is correct to begin with)?

(The given version is the *minimal* version I can use. Updating to a later version is fine.)